# What tool does yum use to download rpm packages from remote server?

Tags: centos, wget, yum, curl, rpm

My system is centos, and now I am installing packages using yum command.

```
Updating for dependencies:
 apr-util           i386      1.3.9-1.el5             lxcenter-updates    203 k
 gcc-gfortran       i386      4.1.2-52.el5_8.1        updates             3.1 M
 libgcc             i386      4.1.2-52.el5_8.1        updates              97 k
 libgfortran        i386      4.1.2-52.el5_8.1        updates             232 k
 libstdc++          i386      4.1.2-52.el5_8.1        updates             363 k
 libstdc++-devel    i386      4.1.2-52.el5_8.1        updates             2.8 M
 php                i386      5.2.17-13               lxcenter-updates    3.5 M
 php-cli            i386      5.2.17-13               lxcenter-updates    2.6 M
 php-common         i386      5.2.17-13               lxcenter-updates    581 k
 php-pdo            i386      5.2.17-13               lxcenter-updates    167 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install      22 Package(s)
Upgrade      17 Package(s)

Total download size: 58 M
Downloading Packages:



[root@localhost ~]# pgrep curl
[root@localhost ~]# pgrep wget

[root@localhost ~]# netstat -nap | grep yum
[root@localhost ~]#
```

From this point, we know the download tool is neither curl or wget, not yum itself either.

So I wonder what tool yum uses to download remote files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses [urlgrabber](http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/) to download the files.

Comment: seems it doesn't use urlgrabber:(  [root@localhost ~]# pgrep urlgrabber  -lf
[root@localhost ~]#            54% [==============================================================>                                                     ] 4,618,214   --.-K/s  eta 6m 29

Comment: Yes it does. urlgrabber is not a program.

Comment: i find it now, it's kind of python script, how did yum invoke it?

Comment: yum [imports it](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) and invokes classes and functions as appropriate.

Comment: lol, yum is also a python script:( i have been using it for years without noticing this fact:(

Answer (score 0):

yumdownloader is also a script (for  manaul "downloading" (--download-only  and /or --downloaddir=foo    usefull for source build/downloading

Comment: The question asks what tool yum uses.  Are you saying it uses yumdownloader rather than urlgrabber?

Comment: the urlgrabber uses  yumdownloader as a wrapper yes